# vectorised solution to change value in pd.df column based on boolean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My df looks like this:

```
              code       date type  strike  settlement
0   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   126.2    1.343750
1   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   131.7    4.359375
2   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   102.5   24.671875
3   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   110.5    0.015625
4   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   101.2    0.015625
5   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   140.5    0.015625
```

i am looking to change the strikes to quarter strikes by doing something like this: if df['strike'] % 0.25 != 0 add 0.05.

Desired output:

```
              code       date type  strike  settlement
0   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   126.25   1.343750
1   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   131.75   4.359375
2   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   102.5   24.671875
3   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   110.5    0.015625
4   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    P   101.25   0.015625
5   CBT_21_G2015_S 2015-01-02    C   140.5    0.015625
```

whats the easiest/fastest way to do this pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little mathemagic with `np.ceil` -

```
df['strike'] = np.ceil(df.strike * 4) / 4
```

```
df
             code        date type  strike  settlement
0  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  126.25    1.343750
1  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  131.75    4.359375
2  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  102.50   24.671875
3  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  110.50    0.015625
4  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  101.25    0.015625
5  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  140.50    0.015625
```

---

It's really fast, as timings show.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit np.ceil(df.strike.values * 4) / 4
5.1 ms ± 60.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `np.where`

```
df.strike = np.where(df.strike % 0.25 == 0, df.strike, df.strike + 0.05)
df

             code        date type  strike  settlement
0  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  126.25    1.343750
1  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  131.75    4.359375
2  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  102.50   24.671875
3  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  110.50    0.015625
4  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    P  101.25    0.015625
5  CBT_21_G2015_S  2015-01-02    C  140.50    0.015625
```